# Mounting volumes in Docker with saving data from the image

Tags: mount, docker

Task: it is necessary when saving a container to save files from an image to a host, provided that the folder to be mounted is empty. For example, the mongodb image (from the documentation) also works.

```
docker run --name some-mongo -v /my/own/datadir:/data/db -d mongo
```

I tested this construction (I work from under Windows), it works fine, the database is saved on the host machine. Making attempts on my image to turn a similar scheme, I get an empty folder in the container, the data from the image completely overlap. I did various tests with Dockerfile and VOLUME, the result is always the same. Dockerfile example:

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN mkdir /myfolder
RUN echo "hello world" > /myfolder/greeting
VOLUME /myfolder
```

I build an image, I launch the container, waiting to get the contents of the folder /myfolder in D:/Docker/, but there is no file.

```
docker run -it -v D:/Docker:/myfolder -d app
```

Folder is empty ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The RUN command is executed during the image construction, so its output is part of the filesystem that defines the image. Your volume is used when the container is run:

```
mkdir /tmp/volume
docker run -v /tmp/volume:/volume ubuntu touch /volume/proof.dat
```

will create a `/tmp/volume/proof.dat` file on the host system.

So in all likelihood you application is not writing to `/data/db`. Once the container is started you can use:

```
docker exec -it {container} bash
```

to execute command in the container environment and so check what files are there. You can also start you container without `-d` to see the application log (or use `docker logs` to obtain the output).

Comment: It turns out, I need to write a BASH script and put it as ENTRYPOINT. Will the script copy files into the mounted folder after launching the container?

Comment: Yes, this should work.